# New control vs control

Tags: vb.net, controls, new-operator, label

Is `New Control` needed to create a control or can one use only `Control`?
For example:

`Dim Label1 As Label`
VS
`Dim Label1 As Label= New Label`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Question 1:

Here you made a reference;

```
 Dim Label1 As Label
```

You can't use this one jet, this won't work;

```
 label1.text = "yadda"
```

You get an error like; object is not an instance of declaring class

Here you made a reference plus an instance;

```
 Dim Label1 As Label= New Label
```

You can now use the instance;

```
 label1.text = "yadde"
```

In .net a 'control' is not a variable, it's a class; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx

#### Question 2:

If you put a control on a form, and then change it, it will also change on the form! You don't have to add them again to the form!

#### Question 3:

Controls.remove is a method of a Form, for example;

```
 Form1.controls.remove(label1)
```

You need to refer to form1 inside it own class as 'me' ;

```
 me.controls.remove(label1)
```

It only detaches the control from the form, but it is stil there.

If you want to 'remove' it you should,

```
    Me.Controls.Remove(Label1)
    Label1.Dispose()
```

Comment: So if I made two instances of a label using the same "blue-print", I wouldn't be able to delete the first instance using the variable (in this case label1) correct?

Comment: Blue-print is poor chosen, the 'label' is the blue-print, label1 is a reference.

Comment: Ok, still will creating a new instance of label1 erase the old instance, or will the control be there but now no longer accessible through the label1 reference?

Comment: Good question, you cannot create a new instance of label1. Label1 only a reference. You can create a new instance of label. Called label2. You can replace the reference of label1 with a new label.

Comment: Can I create a new instance of a label using label1 as a reference again?

Comment: yup:          Dim label1 As New Label
        label1.Text = "blaat"

        label1 = New Label
        ' label.text = not "blaat"

Comment: Yet, doing that I would no longer be able to use the reference to access the previous control.

Comment: exactly! So you could better create a label2... :)